# Closing mongoDB connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Server did not close the connection, and I can't find the error.

When I first access the server (localhost), it returns proper result.

But next time, it sends warnings like

> [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: the options [caseTranslate] is not supported

and some more.
Then it returns "Error"

```
async function report(prodNum) {
    try{
        await client.connect();
        let res = await findOneByprodNum(client, prodNum);
        return res;
    } catch (e){
        return "Error";
    } finally {
        client.close();
    }
}

async function findOneByprodNum(client, prodOfListing) {
    const result = await client.db("mobileContents").collection("food").findOne({
        prodNum: prodOfListing
    });
    if (result) {
        console.log(`Found Name, in: ${prodOfListing}`);
        console.log(result);
        return result;
    } else {
        console.log(`No listings found, in: ${prodOfListing}`);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Client =

```
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    connectTimeoutMS: 30000
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The mongodb JS driver is [not designed to close/reconnect](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-2256?focusedCommentId=2489942&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-2489942)

Connect once in app startup and share the `client`. Close when the node process is to be exited.

```
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    connectTimeoutMS: 30000
});

async function startup(){
    await client.connect()
}

async function shutdown(){
    await client.close()
}

async function report(prodNum) {
    try{
        let res = await findOneByprodNum(client, prodNum);
        return res;
    } catch (e){
        console.error(e)
        return "Error";
    }
}
```